# I am setting up raspberry Pi as cctv camera. Trying to setup email service to send videos to my gmail

Tags: security, email, raspberrypi, postfix

I have successfully setup Postfix as a SMTP server and add the service to my gmail with App Passwords. This is working and I am able to send emails. But there is no attachment options in Postfix. Though I found [sendemail](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/sendEmail.1.html) but I am getting error

`raspberrypi sendemail[4300]: ERROR => Received:  530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. h26sm9164437pfq.139 - gsmtp`

How can I add sendemail to my postfix service?

This is my command -

`sendemail -s smtp.gmail.com:[Port] -f sender@gmail.com -t receiver@gmail.com -m "Message" -u "Subject" -a Attachment_Filename`

Comment: How is this related to Ubuntu?

Comment: OS in Raspberry Pi is Ubuntu...that's why. Do you know any better forum for this question?

Comment: You never mentioned that you've installed Ubuntu.

Comment: Looking at the man page for `sendmail` it doesn't have a switch for attachments.  `mail` on the other hand does.  Look into using `mail` with `postfix` instead of `sendmail`.

Comment: I am actually trying to use sendemail as I mentioned in the post itself. It have attachment option but I am getting this mentioned error. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part.  I still don't see the attachment but then again, I don't have the RPi version.  They change things.  Anyway, look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265692/smtp-server-response-530-5-7-0-must-issue-a-starttls-command-first as your error is about the STARTTLS and not attachments.  Or look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39341137/postfix-must-issue-a-starttls-command-first as I believe you need to set your gmail account in the `main.cf` file.